Can an object oscillate at a frequency below a fundamental frequency (without creating standing waves)?
Is the fundamental frequency the lowest possible frequency at which an object can oscillate, or is it the lowest frequency which the object can oscillate in order to create a standing wave?

it the lowest frequency which the object can oscillate in order to create a standing wave

What exactly do you define as "to oscillate"? Would that imply already that it is in a standing wave? Or that it is not in a standing wave, but instead a wave packet moving back and forth?

A system (which could be a string, a spring, a loudspeaker etc. etc.) can be forced to oscillate at any frequency at all. However at some frequencies, called resonant frequencies, these oscillations will reinforce themselves, typically due to forming standing waves within the system.
A fundamental frequency is a property of a periodic waveform rather than an oscillating system. It is the lowest frequency that is present when that waveform is represented as the sum of a series of sine waves.
